# Angular JS - Update input options with other input options

Tags: angularjs

I have a form where I have to enter a country from a list in order to add different shipping costs to a total. As I am using ngCart directive, I have to use `ng-click` in order to send that info to the directive.

The problem is that I have two different `input options` with the same fields in different parts of the form, and I would like to update the value of one when I manually change the other, so that displayed option is always the same in both inputs.

I attach a http://jsfiddle.net/nf2z1a00/ with my code. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ng-model on the select and use ng-options to take care of the options and the shipping like this:

```
<select ng-model="selectedCountry" ng-options="country.name for country in countries" ng-change="changeChipping()">
</select>
```

I've update your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hr8h5yvw/)

Comment: Works perfect like that. I mark it as correct, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Put same `ng-model` in you similar select boxes :

```
<select ng-model="shippingCountry">
   //first
</select>

<select ng-model="shippingCountry">
   //second : notice the same ng-model
</select>
```

Comment: This solution works just partially, as it doesn't take care of the behaviour that I previously included in the ng-click. Thanks for the insight though!